# ggplot: How to connect points based on columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose that I have geographic data about customers and stores and also in which store the customer made his last purchase. I want to plot customers and stores (according to their coordinates) and connect customers with their respective stores.

Here's a toy dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

customer.data <- data.frame(
  customer = letters[1:12],
  store = rep(paste0("S", 1:3), 4),
  customer.lat = rnorm(12),
  customer.lon = rnorm(12))

store.data <- data.frame(
  customer = NA
  store = paste0("S", 1:3),
  store.lat = rnorm(3),
  store.lon = rnorm(3)
)


data <- left_join(customer.data, store.data, by = "store") %>%
  arrange(store, customer)

ggplot(data, aes(x = customer.lat, y = customer.lon, group = store)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue") +
  geom_point(aes(x = store.lat, y = store.lon), color = "red") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = store))
```

[image]

So I want to do is to connect all customers of S1 store with its point using geom_line() or geom_segment() and so on. How can I do that?

Comment: @MikeH. if I add a geom_line after the first geom_point it will connect the customers within the same store but not them with their stores.

Answer (score 3):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = customer.lat, y = customer.lon)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = store)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = store.lat, y = store.lon, color = store), size = 4) +
  #geom_text_repel(aes(label = store)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = customer.lat, y = customer.lon,
                   xend = store.lat, yend = store.lon,
                   color = store))
```

[image]